# Nested function can't see outer scope

Tags: javascript

I have a function, `LoadList`. Inside this function I have the anonymous function I defined for the `then` part of my promise. The problem is that this inner function can't "see" the `oMembers` variable. I would like to avoid declaring this variable globally. Is it possible?

```
function LoadList() {
    var oMembers = new MyApp.Members();
    var lst = oMembers.getMembersList();

    lst.then(function (result) {
        console.log(oMembers.count())
    });
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle please, because there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: The code you provided (with a contrived version of MyApp), works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/K8k6p/ maybe the `.count()` function isn't on the `oMembers` object but the `lst` object instead

Comment: You guys are very right. The code was fine but the F12 debugger confused me. I appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score -1):

Consider Making LoadList() a class?

```
class OuterClass {
...
static class LoadList{

public function method1() {
    ...
}
private function method2() {
}
```

}

Comment: Did you miss the `javascript` tag on this question?

Comment: That's not possible in JavaScript .

Comment: oops, I did  :/
sorry